# I am getting error ERC1155: transfer to non erc1155 receiver implementer means

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, smart-contract-wallets

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract newToken is ERC1155{
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _nftIds;
    constructor(string memory _uri)ERC1155(_uri){

    }
    function mint(uint _amount,string memory  _uri)public returns(uint){
       _nftIds.increment();
       uint currentId=_nftIds.current();
       _mint(msg.sender,currentId,_amount,"");
       _setURI(_uri);
        return currentId;
    }
    function transfer(address _to,uint _id, uint _amount)public returns(bool success){
        safeTransferFrom(
         msg.sender,
         _to,
         _id,
         _amount,
        ""
    ) ;
    return true;

    }
    

}


contract createContract{
    newToken[] contractAddress;
    mapping(address=>newToken) public contracts;

    function create(string memory _uri) public {
        newToken addr=new newToken(_uri);
        contractAddress.push(addr);
        contracts[msg.sender]=addr;
    }
    function mint(string memory _uri)public  returns(newToken)  {
        if (address(contracts[msg.sender])==address(0)){
            create(_uri);
            contracts[msg.sender].mint(1,_uri);
            return contracts[msg.sender];

        }
        else{
            contracts[msg.sender].mint(1,_uri);
            return contracts[msg.sender];
        }
        
    }

}
```

When I try to deploy createContract and mint I am getting an error
**ERC1155: transfer to non erc1155 receiver implementer means .**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `createContract` calls the `mint` function on one of your `newToken` contracts it will become the `msg.sender`. Therefore it will mint a `newToken` to your `createContract`.

By definition ERC-1155 contract will check if the receiver of a token transfer is a contract and if this is the case call `onERC1155Received` (see [ERC-1155 Token Receiver](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155#erc-1155-token-receiver)). This also applies when you mint a new token (as it is transferred). Therefore your `newToken` tries to call this method on your `createContract` contract, but this one does not implement it.

There are some ways around this. For example adding the `receiver` to the mint function and specify it to be the account that calls the `createContract`.

Currently your `newToken` can also be minted by anyone, so it might also make sense to make it ownable and make the `createContract` that is the only account that can mint the token ... but this is more a design decision on your side ;)

Answer (score 1):

Need `ERC1155Holder` in your contract.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/utils/ERC1155Holder.sol";

contract myContract is ERC1155Holder{}
```

Answer (score 0):

See example at https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/mocks/ERC1155ReceiverMock.sol

any contract to receive ERC1155 should be written this way:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC1155/IERC1155ReceiverUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/introspection/ERC165Upgradeable.sol";

contract ERC1155StakingUpgradeable is
    ERC165Upgradeable, 
    IERC1155ReceiverUpgradeable {

    //copy code from https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/mocks/ERC1155ReceiverMock.sol

    function initialize() external initializer {
        ...
        _recRetval = 0xf23a6e61;//function signature copied from OpenZeppelin IERC1155ReceiverUpgradeable.sol
        _batRetval = 0xbc197c81;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error while testing an `ERC1155` contract in Foundry while trying to `_mint`. The error was something like: `[FAIL. Reason: ERC1155InvalidReceiver(0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496)]` .

@Richard's answer seems to explain why - I was attempting to call `_mint` with `msg.sender`, which was the contract address. If you are getting this error in testing in Foundry, you can fix it by calling the contract using a `prank` user. `Prank` users simulate another wallet address that isn't a deployed contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;
import { Test, console } from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import { MyContract } from "../src/MyContract.sol";

contract MyContractTest is Test {

    MyContract myContract;

    // create prank user
    address user = makeAddr("user");
    
    function setUp() external {
        // ... (deploy your contract)

        // add 10 ether to fake user account
        vm.deal(user, 10 ether);
    }

    function testWithPrankUser() public {
        // use "user" because msg.sender is a contract address, which creates complications
        vm.prank(user); // only the next line will be called by "user" address
        MyContract.myMintFunction(); // myMintFunction may call _mint from within it

        // ... continue test
    }
}
```